# No admin account in macOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, administrator

I know this has been answered before with the whole "rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone" thing in High Sierra but when I try to do this, I'm told that it's a "read only file system". Is this because I have my SSD encrypted?

Whatever the case, I'd really appreciate a work around.

Answer (score 2):

When launching single-user mode, you're informed with the following text that you need to mount the disk as writable before you can make changes.

> ```
> Root device is mounted read only
>
> If you want to make modifications to files:
>         /sbin/fsck -fy
>         /sbin/mount -uw /
> ```

This text is printed when you launch single-user mode. Do as it says to mount with write access.